# JW Player load function with multiple quality

Tags: jwplayer

I setup jw player with qualities like this.

```
sources: [
            {
                "file":"url_of_video.mp4", 
                "label":"1080p", 
                "type": "mp4",
            },
            {
                "file":"url_of_video.mp4", 
                "label":"720p", 
                "type": "mp4",
            },
            {
                "file":"url_of_video.mp4", 
                "label":"480p", 
                "type": "mp4",
                "default": "true"
            },
            {
                "file":"url_of_video.mp4", 
                "label":"360p", 
                "type": "mp4",
            }

        ]
```

I want to change video sources with load function like this as mentioned on jwplayer developer site.

```
jwplayer('myElement').load([{
    "file": "/videos/myVideo.mp4",
    "image": "/images/myImage.png",
    "title": "My Favorite Video!",
    "description": "This has lots of kittens in it!"
}]);
```

But in all examples there is only 1 video url. I tried to replace "file" string with sources array but it didn't work. Is there another function to do this or what is the right syntax for this.
Thanks so much.

Comment: where you are hosting it ? for example, does `www.example.com/videos/myVideo.mp4` has video stored in your server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the one file: ' ' parameter in your second code example with the sources: [] block and it should work:

```
jwplayer('your_div').setup({
    sources: [{
        file: 'video 1 URL'
        label: 'video 1 quality'
    },{
        file: 'video 2 URL'
        label: 'video 2 quality'
    },{
        file: 'video 3 URL'
        label: 'video 3 quality'    
    }]
});
```

Please see https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1428524-hd-quality-toggling for more details.